# Strange beeline error: "Error: (state=,code=0)"

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-streaming

I'm seeing a very strange error when running my HiveQL through beeline:

```
Error:  (state=,code=0)
Error:  (state=,code=0)
Aborting command set because "force" is false and command failed: "create table some_database.some_table..."
```

My query is quite complex, utilizing UNIONS and transforms, but it runs fine when I submit it using the Hive client. It looks something like this:

```
create table some_database.some_table
stored as rcfile
as select * from (

  from some_other_db.table_1 
  select transform (*) 
  using "hdfs:///some/transform/script.py" 
  as ( 
    some_field_1 string, 
    some_field_2 double
  )

  union all 

  from some_other_db.table_2 
  select transform (*) 
  using "hdfs:///some/transform/script.py" 
  as ( 
    some_field_1 string, 
    some_field_2 double
  ) 

  union all 

  from some_other_db.table_3 
  select transform (*) 
  using "hdfs:///some/transform/script.py" 
  as ( 
    some_field_1 string, 
    some_field_2 double
  ) 

) all_unions
;
```

I'm using:

- CDH 4.3.0-1
- Hive 0.10.0-cdh4.3.0
- Beeline version 0.10.0-cdh4.3.0